# How to test a component in prop element with React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm doing testing with Jest and Enzyme in React. I have a component like this:

```js
function Component() {
  const renderProps = <>
    ...
  </>
  return (
   <ComponentReact prop1={renderProp} >
  )
}
```

I would like to know how to test a component that is rendered within a prop.

Comment: The kind of test you do depends on what the component does ... if it has no logic and is simply presentational, you are likely looking for snapshot tests, of which there is tons of Jest / Enzyme documentation.

Comment: `render prop` term is for function that is passed as a prop and returns some JSX after been called. In you sample `renderProps` variable is just JSX block, not a callback. so what thing do you actually have? also do you use `mount()` or `shallow()`? If first one, you should not care how and what props are passed, just check render output against `wrapper.find(...)`